# php delegating intensive tasks

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a mailing feature for my application where the user can send emails to every subscriber. The issue is that this can take quite a while depending on the number of subscribers. I'd like to have it where the user will write the message and send it to the server. Then the server would "delegate" the task to be executed outside of the http request. That way a "transaction" id could be sent to the client which in turn could periodically "poll" the server to check the progress on the email transaction. What are some ways (or A way) that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a message queue ('Message' and 'Job' can be used interchangeably in this context). It works by popping a message onto the queue that contains information about the job to be done. Workers are constantly checking the queue for new messages. Once found, the worker takes ownership of the message, removing it from the queue, and does whatever it's programmed to do.

I've used [Gearman](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) in the past. They have some pretty [good examples](http://us.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples.php) that demonstrate the basics of message queues.

- [Simple Reverse Example](http://us.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse.php)
- [Background Tasks](http://us.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-bg.php)

There are two types of jobs: Foreground and Background.

### Foreground Jobs

Foreground jobs are blocking in that your PHP code will wait for the job to complete before continuing. This is intended to offload the hardware-intensive processing to a worker (most-likely running on a different server than the webhead).

### Background Jobs

Background jobs are not blocking. These are jobs that are sent to the queue and assumed to be worked at a later time. A good example of this would be a report that's generated by a query that takes several minutes to run and emailed (or otherwise sent) to the user when ready.

Comment: is there any way to do this without writing a php "server"? if not, how badly does it affect perfomance? i'm running my application on a EC2 micro instance which only has 512mb of ram

Comment: ok, i was looking at the examples, and how would it work to check on the progress of a job with separate http requests?