# run server side php code withouth waiting any return

Tags: php, json

i'm looking for a way to run a function on my server to zip multiple files (operation can be long).

I wrote the code to do that (it works) but my problem is that my browser wait a respons from the server (i call my function with an json call) and it's too long for waiting. Client-side don't care what the server is doing, is anyone know if it is possible to ask my server to do that without waiting any respons ? the finale situation i want is the client can do anything else during the zip operation but now it is not possible.

PS: sorry for my bad engligh, i've do the best i can...sorry.

server side :

```
public function zipAction() {
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(43000);
$uid = $this->getParam('uid');
if (isset($uid)) {
    $fileName = $uid . '.zip';
    $filter = new Zend_Filter_Compress(array(
        'adapter' => 'Zip',
        'options' => array(
            'archive' => $fileName
        )
    ));
    if ($filter->filter('uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $uid)) {
        foreach (glob('uploads/' . $uid . '/*') as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir('uploads/' . $uid);
    rename($uid . '.zip', 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $uid . '.zip');
}
$this->_helper->json->sendJson(....);
}
```

clietn side :

```
$.getJSON('index/zip', {'uid': uid});
```

Thanking you in advance,

Xavier

Comment: Lookup `ignore_user_abort` and `background process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a point where [delegating tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089073/php-delegating-intensive-tasks) is a good idea.

You may use a queue server of any kind with workers that will do that for you, this will also reduce the intensity on your server if the ziping operation will be requested multiple times at once.

You may do it really easily by writing the task to your database and having a `CRON` job to constantly read one-two tasks and perform them. The other way [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/), IronMQ or any other (there are dozens, literally). If you're using any framework, it probably already has everything needed to get you going in a really short time.

Comment: thank you for you quick answer, i use Zend Framework 1.12 but i don't find a simple way to do that, i'm using keywork like "delegating tasks". The only thing i've found is the Action Helper "Action Stack but i don't know how to close browser connection before executing my script. I'll continue my quest ^^ thank you.

Comment: The point is with queue systems the only action your page performs is describes the task like you write to the queue `{'action': 'zip', 'id':5}`, then some CRON job reads the queue as a background process (run by system as CLI, not the visitor of website) and begins to perform the same task